# Using tar for backup; can I run it to show ALL the errors before backing up?

Tags: backup, tar

I am trying to use tar to backup but keep getting the error that it's "exiting due to previous errors."  The solution is to (obviously) exclude the offending files/dirs with --exclude, which I am doing.

But the problem is that I'm running tar for hours and hours, half a day each time, only to find ONE error, fixing that, then running it again for half a day to find that there's another error...fixing that.  And so on.  It's been days now.  I would love to be able to run it with a flag that just tells it to churn through start to finish and list ALL the errors for me.  The man page has something about "ignore child errors" but I don't understand what that means.

Most of these errors are ridiculously unnecessary, too.  So if there's a way to just see ALL the expected errors at once, I can write an exclude file that has them all there, run tar once and for all, and be done.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tar completes the run as best it can. There can be transient errors that would not occur on a second run: for example, if a file is modified or deleted between the time tar scans the directories to find out what it has to do, and the time it actually writes it out. Logs can get appended to, for example.

Can you give examples of the type of error you get? Having a file change under you is probably unfixable. If you are supplying specific  filenames (e.g. with -T option or a find command) you could script separately to check if the files are all existing and readable.

You could also tar -tv the archive, compare to find what was missing, and put those names into a separate addendum tar.

Comment: Also notice that GNU tar has a --warning=KEYWORD option.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I have 2 types of errors, one is "socket ignored" errors which don't seem to be fatal.  The others are caused by files that for some reason have perms set to 400 and the only user able to do anything with them is User 1000.  I haven't quite investigated the option of su-ing to User 1000 and THEN running the "sudo tar --exclude=/blah/blah" etc. But that'd be the next step.  It's frustrating because it runs mainly through the .config and .cache and .such-and-such dirs first, finding weird files and failing on those, BEFORE getting to the dirs and subdirs.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant That GNU tar option is a cheap copy of the `errctl=xxx` option from `star`. You better should have a look at `star`, see http://cdrtools.sourceforge.net/private/man/star/star.1.html for a reference on the features.

Comment: BTW: It is recommended to run backups with `star -cM -dump ....` as this is using an enhanced archive format that supports all file types. So your socket problem will go away. If you are on the file server that has the filesystem locally, the permission problems should go away when the backup is run as root.

Comment: You should consider researching star, if you can install additional packages. Also, google GNU Tar Manual, and find the section "Excluding some files". Sockets and named pipes are special comms files that tar would hang if it actually read them. User 1000 is probably the first non-system user but may be a database admin, for example. Using sudo tar would be helpful.

Comment: Well, I'm familiar with tar and would prefer to use that.  Really, the question is just whether there's a way to "query" tar and get the errors.  But in reading your notes above, if I get a "tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors" message, does that mean that it DID complete?  Just that there were errors?  Because the ones that I'm seeing aren't anything I need to back up.  If the file is still usable and complete except for those errors, maybe I'm all set as is.  Should I try restoring the file and see what I get for a backup?

Comment: `star` is closer to the behavior of `tar` than `GNU tar` is, so if you are familiar with `tar`, that would be an argument for `star`.

Comment: Options --list or -t (as in tar -tv my.tar > my.toc) will read the whole archive and list the files (much like ls -l on a disc). It at least shows that all the file control blocks are in place, and that no detectable media errors occurred. You can also compare the line counts of the .toc are similar to those found by a find of the same directory tree. There is also a --compare option (which compares files on the archive with their originals, but does NOT warn of files that are not in the archive) and a --verify option that checks the physical accuracy of the archive as it is written.

Comment: If you have an archive created with `star -c -dump ...`, you may run a configurable `star -diff ...` of the archive against the filesystem. This reports files that are missing on either side and allows to specify which meta data to compare by using the `diffopts=xxx` option.